# Does Array.prototype.some() return a literal? If so, what does this code mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

An example from an oreilly book on node and express:

```
var tours = [
  {id:0, name: 'test', price: 0.0},
  {id:1, name: 'test2', price: 0.2}
];

app.put('/api/tour/:id', function(req, res){
  var p = tours.some(function(p){return p.id == req.params.id });
  if (p) {
    if (req.query.name) p.name = req.query.name;
    if (req.query.price) p.price = req.query.price;
    res.json({success:true;});
  } else {
    res.json({error: 'No such tour exists.'});
  }
});
```

Let's say p returns true, am I right in assuming that attempting to assign a property to p isn't going to work?

Comment: Yep, if it's true, this won't work. Are you sure that's the same code that's in the book?

Comment: Positive. It isn't even included in the errata. Here's a link to the example in the free preview on google books:

http://books.google.com/books?id=1cHvAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=var+p+%3D+tours.some%28function&source=bl&ots=BqtYrbSuf4&sig=rlkLOAj4h0ZgBWWp_QEFUqmahGc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hjRxVLLYM6nbiQLBuIDIBA&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=var%20p%20%3D%20tours.some(function&f=false

It's example 6-13

Comment: Now I know never to read or recommend "Web Development with Node and Express: Leveraging the JavaScript Stack" By Ethan Brown. This code isn't even close to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Array.prototype.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns a boolean value. This is a *primitive* value, not a "literal".

You are correct that if `p` holds a boolean value then assigning properties like `p.name` will *not* work.

(However, I believe it will only result in an exception if the code is running in strict mode otherwise the attempted assignment will fail silently.)

Even if assigning those `.name` and `.price` properties worked that code still doesn't quite make sense because `p` is a local variable that is not referenced again within that function. It would only make sense if `.some()` returned a reference to the matching array element, because *then* it would be an object and the code would update the properties of that object.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I did in fact mean "primitive" in my question.

Comment: And now you can file an errata with O'Reilly.